# CSS unexpected behaviour when using ~ (tilde) with comma

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to build an input field that has a dropdown of possible options, but that dropdown should only be showing when the input is in the 'active' state (`:active`).

Here's an example of how this looked:

```
.country-input:active ~ .country-dropdown.active{
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

(`country-input` is the input field, `country-dropdown` is the dropdown.)

Problem is, as soon as I try to click the button to select an element, the input field looses its active state, so the dropdown hides before I'm able to click.

So I changed the selector to the following:

```
.country-input:active ~ .country-dropdown.active, .country-input ~ .country-dropdown:hover
```

But now the dropdown only shows when the mouse is pressed inside the input field.

Comment: _The :active pseudo selector changes the appearance of a link while it is being activated (being clicked on or otherwise activated). It's usually only seen for a split second, and provides visual feedback that the element was indeed clicked. It's most typically used on anchor links (<a href="#">). _  from [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 but it behaved as expected when the selector was only the part before the comma. Only once I added the second part did it start to misbehave.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.country-input:focus ~ .country-dropdown.active` too?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `:active` with `:focus` did the trick since the latter is toggled when an element is in focus (duh), and for a input field that is true when it's possible to write into it (when it's selected).